# NSInvocation object not getting allocated iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, nsinvocation

I'm doing

```
        NSString *_type_ = @"report";
        NSNumber *_id_ = [NSNumber numberWithInt:report.reportId];

        NSDictionary *paramObj = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                _id_, @"bla1", _type_, @"bla2",nil];

_operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(initParsersetId:) object:paramObj];
```

But my _operation object is nil even after processing this line.

The selector here is actually a function I'm writing which is like:

```
-(void)initParsersetId:(NSInteger)_id_ type:(NSString *)_type_
{   
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"apimediadetails?id=624&type=report"];
NSString *finalURLstr = [urlStr stringByAppendingString:URL];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:finalURLstr];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//Initialize the delegate.
DetailedViewObject *parser = [[DetailedViewObject alloc] initDetailedViewObject];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
```

}

Can anybody please point out wheather where I'm going wrong.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@selector` doesn't match your method signature, which is why it's returning nil. Also, you can't use the convenience constructor to pass multiple parameters. You'll have to create an `NSInvocation` and use `initWithInvocation:`to add the parameters.

http://theocacao.com/document.page/264

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided, but in initWithTarget:selector:object: ,can't I pass arguments in an nsdictionary object directly? I've to do this process for as many as 10 different nsinvocationobjects and the approach by Scott Stevenson [which is awesome], will I think introduce redundancy in my case. Also it's not getting allocated after changing the method signature.

Comment: You can't pass arguments in an `NSDictionary`. `NSInvocation` objects are mutable, so you can just edit the same object for each of your 10 different method calls.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your selector is `initWithParserId:type:`, so the correct line is

```
_operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(initParsersetId:type:) object:paramObj];
```

Comment: No, it's still not getting allocated..:(